# QString::fromWCharArray avoiding new line char "\n"

Tags: qt, qstring

Received wchar_t message from server as **"TextmesageComing\nSomeValueObserveany\ntruncationOccuringonthescreenwhiletestingthescenation"**
so i used `QString` converter

```
QString textName = QString::fromWCharArray(smartAlertMessages_.text);
```

to draw text on `QPainter` drawText

```
painter->drawText(messageRect, Qt::TextWordWrap | Qt::TextWrapAnywhere, text);
```

but observed the `"\n"` characters are not considered as new line and start displaying `\n` as a part of the text .

Same text if i hard code in drawText is working properly.

Comment: Are you sure that the `\n` isn't encoded as `"\\n"` in your `message`? You may check this in your debugger. If `\n` occurs in a C string literal in C++ source code (what you probably meant with _hard code_) then the C++ compiler translates `"\n"` into byte 0x0a. If a string contains characters `\\ ` and `n` after compilation then there is nothing built-in which will consider this. In this case, you have to apply a resp. filter on your own.

Comment: "\n" is only interpreted as newline if it is in a string literal, not if it is read from elsewhere. If your want to have a data from a server interpreted that way, you must do something like `s.replace("\\n", "\n")`.